# Beginner's questions about Hidden Markov Models

Tags: markov-chains, machine-learning, bayesian-network

I have started reading about Hidden Markov Models, and have some (more or less) minor questions about things I am not sure I understood correctly. I hope asking here is fine:

---

**1.** Assumption about the conditional independence of observations: One of the independence assumptions is that an observation is independent of previous observations. I read that mathematically, this can be formulated:

$$ p(\textbf{O} | q_1,q_2,q_3,..,q_T) = \prod_{t=1}^T p(o_t | q_t) ,$$ with $\textbf{O}$ a chain of observations with observations $o_t$, and the $q_t$ the states at time point t.

My question here: I understand that if we assume conditional independence of the observations from each other, by the definition of conditional independence we arrive at:

$ p(\textbf{O} | q_1,q_2,q_3,..,q_T) = \prod_{t=1}^T p(o_t | q_1,q_2,...,q_T) $ - **but don't we need the assumption that the current observation $o_i$ is only dependent on the state $q_i$ to arrive at $\prod_{t=1}^T p(o_t | q_t)$?**

---

**2.** Homogeneity HMM: Hidden Markov Models are time homogeneous - **why exactly is this assumption made?**

I see that the assumptions of conditional independence are useful for solving some problems regarding HMMs quickly, **but what use does the assumption of homogeneity have?**

---

**3.** Again about the independence of observations: Even though an observation $o_i$ is not dependent on any previous observation, it is conditionally dependent on the state $q_i$.

$q_i$ in turn is because of the Markov property (only) dependent on $q_{i-1}$ - **so how come $o_i$ is not dependent on $q_{i-1}$?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you really looked at a hidden markov model in graphical form? I'm guessing a lot of things would become clearer if you did so.

For (1) Yes, you need to have [the Markov property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property) to show that $p(\mathbf{O_t}|q_1, q_2,\ldots, q_T) = \prod_t p(o_t|q_t)$. Otherwise, you would have the more general expression.

Let me just demonstrate with a simple example. Imagine we have only 3 states and the corresponding observations. We want to find $p(o_1, o_2, o_3 | q_1, q_2, q_3)$.

Assume we have the following undirected model. (Colors and shading don't mean anything.):

[image]

Based on this graph, you should be able to convince yourself of the following conditional independencies. If not, then it's a good idea to study probabilistic graphical models.

**Given** $q_1$, $o_1$ is independent of the rest of the graph, i.e. $q_2, o_2, q_3, o_3$. From this we can infer: $$p(o_1, o_2, o_3 | q_1, q_2, q_3) = p(o_1 | q_1, q_2, q_3) p(o_2, o_3 | q_1, q_2, q_3) = p(o_1 | q_1) p(o_2, o_3 | q_1, q_2, q_3)$$

**Given** $q_2$, $o_2$ is independent of the rest of the graph. From this, we can infer: $$p(o_2, o_3 | q_1, q_2, q_3) = p(o_2 | q_2) p(o_3 | q_1, q_2, q_3)$$

**Given** $q_3$, $o_3$ is independent of the rest of the graph. Thus, $p(o_3 | q_1, q_2, q_3) = p(o_3 | q_3)$.

As a result, we have: $$p(o_1, o_2, o_3 | q_1, q_2, q_3) = p(o_1 | q_1)p(o_2 | q_2)p(o_3 | q_3)$$

For (3), I think you are getting confused about dependence and conditional independence. Observation $o_i$ is **dependent** on any observation $o_{k}$ AND $p_{k}$ for any $k \not = i$. Nonetheless, **GIVEN $p_i$**, $o_i$ is **independent** of $o_k$ and $p_k$ for any $k \not = i$.

I would recommend [these lecture videos](https://class.coursera.org/pgm-003/lecture) from Daphne Coller's coursera course to review flow of influence in Bayesian Networks and Markov Networks.

Comment: For (1) I am not sure I follow yet. So if we have P(o_t l q_1,..q_t)*P(o2 l, q_1,..,q_t), the Markov property just says that P(q_t l q_(t-1),q(t_2)...) = P(q_t l q(t-1)) - how does that formally imply P(o_t l q_1,..q_t) = P(o_t l q_t) - the later seems to be a statement on the independence of o_t from the q_j with j != k, not of the states from each other. Regarding (3) do you mean k < i?

Comment: For (1), see my edited answer. You need to understand the conditional independencies. Once you understand those, it'll become clear.

Comment: For (3), no, any two nodes on an HMM are dependent. Think of it like this. If I tell you an observation at time t, now have you have evidence about the state at time t - you'll be able to guess the state better knowing the observation. But because you have evidence about the state at t, you now have evidence about state at time t+1 and t-1. But now you can make an inference about the state at time t+2 and t-2. Everything is dependent if nothing is given.